# How to fix ActionText image attachment link resulting in error 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actiontext

I am trying to run a very simple CMS of a page with Action Text on my own server.

In development it all works fine. The attachment is uploaded and I can see it after saving my page model.

When switching to production the upload still works and I can see the file on the local file system, but viewing the page shows a broken image tag.

The link for the image looks like

```
http://example.com/rails/active_storage/representations/SIGNED_ID/myimage.png
```

On my local production the link is:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/gsid/myimage.png?content_type=image%2Fpng&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22myimage.png%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27myimage.png
```

I have provided a `secrete_key_base`, white-listed my host and all the stuff to get the application running for production.

I am using:

- Unicorn
- Nginx
- Ruby 2.6.5
- Rails 6.0.2.1

My storage service is "Disk" and all files and folders inside, including the `RAILS_ROOT` are owned by the user running the application.

storage.yml:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

routes.rb:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages, param: :seo_url, path: 'seite'

  get '/index', to: 'application#home', as: :home
  root to: 'application#home'
end
```

production.rb:

```rb
  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Does anyone have a clue why this does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. I misconfigured my Nginx. I pasted the wrong config snippet for static image delivery into the config. 
I removed the lines from the Nginx config. Everything is working fine now.

This is actually so embarrassing!

Comment: can you share your nginx config, cause i am facing the same problem and i don't know what am i missing